# How to align icons in a sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have the following menu items in a sidebar but the icons won't align vertically, for example, the item Cakes is not aligned with the others....How can I get them all aligned?

```css
#menu .menu-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D8D9;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    color: #6B6A72;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#menu .menu-item i {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#menu .menu-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6B6A72;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#menu .menu-item:hover, #menu .menu-item-active {
    border-right: 5px solid #45B29D;
    color: #45B29D;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu .menu-item:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#menu .menu-item:hover a, #menu .menu-item-active a {
    color: #45B29D;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="menu" class="section">
                <div class="menu-item"><a href="index.html"><span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span> Orders</a></div>
                <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></span> Cakes</a></div>
                <div class="menu-item"><a href="login.html"><span class="fa fa-sign-out"></span> Signout</a></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: They seem to be center aligned correctly. Do you want them left-aligned but centered in the container?

Answer (score 2):

This is how to align the images with the css:

```css
#menu .menu-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D8D9;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    color: #6B6A72;



}

#menu .menu-item i {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#menu .menu-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6B6A72;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
     margin-left: 50%;
}

#menu .menu-item:hover, #menu .menu-item-active {
    border-right: 5px solid #45B29D;
    color: #45B29D;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu .menu-item:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#menu .menu-item:hover a, #menu .menu-item-active a {
    color: #45B29D;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="menu" class="section">
                <div class="menu-item"><a href="index.html"><span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span> Orders</a></div>
                <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></span> Cakes</a></div>
                <div class="menu-item"><a href="login.html"><span class="fa fa-sign-out"></span> Signout</a></div>
            </div>
```

```
#menu .menu-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D8D9;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    color: #6B6A72;



}

#menu .menu-item i {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#menu .menu-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6B6A72;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
     margin-left: 50%;
}

#menu .menu-item:hover, #menu .menu-item-active {
    border-right: 5px solid #45B29D;
    color: #45B29D;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu .menu-item:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#menu .menu-item:hover a, #menu .menu-item-active a {
    color: #45B29D;
}
```